# Spring Boot API: Failing to save object to Database using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have already built projects similar to this one, I even based this one in a different project I have. Thing is, I don't see why it keeps failing when I try to save an object to the Database. These are my Classes:

Car

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "cars")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column
    @NotBlank
    private String brand;
    @Column
    @NotBlank
    private String model;
    @Column
    @NotBlank
    private String color;
    @Column
    @NotBlank
    private int kilometers;
    @Column(name = "fabrication_date")
    private LocalDate fabricationDate;
    @Column
    @PositiveOrZero
    private float price;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "------------------------------------------------------------"+ "\n"
                +brand + " - " + model;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "car")
    @JsonBackReference(value = "car-purchases")
    private List<Purchase> purchases;
}
```

Purchase

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "purchases",
        uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = 
                { "user_id", "car_id" }) })
public class Purchase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private LocalDate creationDate;

    @Column
    private float price;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_id")
    private Car car;
}
```

This is the Add to Database function:

```
    @Override
    public CarOutDTO addCar(CarInDTO carInDTO) {
        Car car = new Car();
        modelMapper.map(carInDTO, car);
        car.setFabricationDate(LocalDate.now());
        car.setKilometers(0);
        Car newCar = carRepository.save(car); <--- It fails here

        CarOutDTO carOutDTO = new CarOutDTO();
        modelMapper.map(car, carOutDTO);
        return carOutDTO;
    }
```

And, this is the info that comes when I try sending a POST:
[image]

I can't find the error here, I assume it has something to do with this part, maybe the @JsonBackReference part?

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "car")
    @JsonBackReference(value = "car-purchases")
    private List<Purchase> purchases;
```

Comment: How does it fail? Does the computer shut down? Do you get an exception? Please add the stack trace.

Comment: @JensSchauder it gives no info nor exception info, app doesnt stop either... it throws a 500 and thats all... I've tried running the database in a docker to see the logs and all it says when I try to POST is "mbind: Operation not permitted"

Comment: We need to see the error here. Can you debug code? If you can see car/carDto content in debug, then you can go into save method and see what is the issue there. Without an error, it is hard to do anything, it can be wrong DB connection, can be repository null-pointer, and lot more